# Implementing Full text search on encrypted data

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search

In one of my use cases I need to provide the similar experience people have while they search their mailbox like Gmail. It can search through both email subject and body.

I have some support tickets saved in Postgres. These tickets contain user messages which we can't store in plain text. We have to encrypt the data. Now if we want to build an index for providing full text search how do we go about it considering the index can't contain the actual data

Any pointer on how Gmail or any other similar providers solve this problem would also be great.

Comment: Do you need one key globally or one per user or one per message, or what?

Comment: What makes you think Gmail does solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. Either data are encrypted or not. If they are encrypted, the database does not know the value, so it cannot perform full text search. That's pretty obvious.

Security comes at a price, and in this case, it is performance.

Comment: You dismiss it so quickly.  Think outside the box.  It is certainly conceivable a mechanism could be devised to allow indexing encrypted, or perhaps hashed, terms in such a way that even though they are encrypted, they can be queried/searched.

Comment: @TonySchwartz I like your hopeful attitude. However, indexes are maintained by the database, not by the application. Can you tell me how the database should parse, stem and index the clear text data, if it only has the encrypted data? Any solution for this must involve the application, it cannot be a database index (which the question asked about). So you are right, this requires thinking out of the box, where the box is the database. Since any such "index" (not an index in the database sense) must contain clear text data, it will compromise security.

Answer (score 0):

PostGreSQL is not able to encrypt data at the storage level as Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server do with [Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_data_encryption). When Using TDE the data are encrypted in the storage files, not in memory so, you can use a fulltext search as usual.